# How to make the data in a python dictionary accessible in Flask/sqlALchemy?

Tags: python, database, dictionary, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to programming and as a hand-on project, I am trying to make a Web App where  I could gather recipes I *scraped* and where I could search rapidly for a recipe to do.
**All the data I collect from the *scraping* are in a nested dictionary with Python saved as a pickle, each new *scraping* adding data to the dictionary.**
I chose a nested dictionary because of some elements being lists as 'keywords','ingredients' or 'instructions' but maybe there is a simplier way to make it work.

```
{0: {
  'title': 'Le tigre qui pleure',
  'imgfile': '../static/images/tigre-qui-pleure.jpg',
  'keywords': ['Main course','Spring'],
  'yieldnumber': '2',
  'preptime': 20,
  'cookingtime': 15,
  'ingredients': ['A bit of this','A bit of that',"This'n that"],
  'instructions': ['Do that','Do this',"Do this 'n that"],
  'dateimport': '17/05/2021'},
1:...}
}
```

I have **created a web App with flask/SQLAlchemy** so that I could make searches in my dictionary based on ingredients or key words.
**I cannot see how to transform my dictionary in something(db?) I can use in my WebApp**.
I have read about a SQL injection that I could do...
Is this the right path for my project or is there something more straightforward to do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish.

Comment: Sorry! I am French! But thank you for letting me know, I hate doing that kind of mistake :-)

Comment: Why can't the web app just read the dictionary? Using that as a source shouldn't be an issue; it'll just mean you have to implement the search functions against the dictionary itself.

Comment: I have managed to do that and I have succeeded in creating a table with SQL Alchemy that imports all the data from a csv(dictionary transformed in csv)